# Maven build fails even after unit test is successful

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a sample to demonstrate unit testing with spring batch. During maven build I could see that the unit test executed successfully but still build fails with below error.

Batch test executed successfully. Below is the output

```
2019-09-29 16:30:43.276  INFO 8065 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2019-09-29 16:30:43.402  INFO 8065 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=transactionProcessingJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2019-09-29 16:30:43.434  INFO 8065 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [transactionImportStep]
Hibernate: call next value for transaction_entry_seq
Hibernate: call next value for transaction_entry_seq
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction_entry (account_no, amount, transaction_date, transaction_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-09-29 16:30:43.696  INFO 8065 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=transactionProcessingJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

After unit text execution, build fails with below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]         ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Full source code of the sample is available [here](https://github.com/st-spring-batch-samples/unit-testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spring Batch v4.1+, you can add the `@SpringBatchTest` annotation on your test class and it will automatically add the `JobLauncherTestUtils` bean to your test context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JobConfiguration.class})
public class JobTest {

  @Autowired
  private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

  // use jobLauncherTestUtils in test methods

}
```

Please check the [What's new](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewTesting) section for a complete example. You will find more details in the [unit testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass) section.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So the root cause of my initial failure is to let the job run the second time. Adding 'spring.batch.job.enabled=false' property to my test resources would have been fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your test is not executed. It does not start because of application context failure on start. To fix the test you need to add missed dependency (`JobLauncherTestUtils`). To do this I would propose to add test context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TransactionBatchApplication.class, TransactionBatchTests.TestConfig.class})
//@Transactional
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.batch.job.enabled=false"})
public class TransactionBatchTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionEntryRepository transactionEntryRepository;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertThat("COMPLETED").isEqualTo(jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        assertThat(transactionEntryRepository.count()).isEqualTo(18);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have disabled `@Transactional` because of:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
```

And I would recommend to change values in assertion, (actual and expected):

```
assertThat(transactionEntryRepository.count()).isEqualTo(10);
```

After that check if 10 is valid expected value, because actual is 18, not sure which one is correct.

So after changing expected value to 18 you will get it green.

Comment: The job is working now with the changes, but the expected value 18 is wrong, it is 9 instead (number of rows in 'transactions.csv'). I looked at the logs and found that the job is running twice.

Comment: With 'spring.batch.job.enabled=false' property, the batch is not running twice and test pass with correct expected value 9. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just added the fix to the test (`@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.batch.job.enabled=false"})`). But you found this this.

Comment: Manually adding the `JobLauncherTestUtils` bean to the test context is the way to go in Spring Batch v4.0 and previous versions. So this is a correct answer. In v4.1, there is a new annotation named `@SpringBatchTest` that adds it automatically (See my answer for an example).